# Сложить два числа

Tags: javascript

Как сложить числа? Соединяет как будто это строка

```
stoimost = Number(cena1+ Number((cena1*0.1)*5))*dni+" р.";
```

Comment: `(+cena1 + cena1 * 0.5) * dni + ' p.'`

Comment: `cena1*1.5*dni + ' p.'` ))

Comment: `(Number(cena1) + Number((cena1*0.1)*5))*dni+" р."` если применять ваш подход. Просто скобку сдвиньте и все. А так у вас в первом случае `cena1` - строка, при суммировании она приводит и второй операнд к строке. Из-за этого вся ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Метод `Number()` нужен лишь в том случае если операция `сложения`,которая может трактоваться не однозначно, в других его можно опустить. Так же можно использовать шаблонную строку для того чтобы добавить рубли, и `toFixed` для предотвращения мелких дробей.

```js
const cena1 = "42.05";
const dni = "1";
const stoimost = `${((Number(cena1) + cena1 * 0.1 * 5) * dni
).toFixed(2)}р.`;

console.log(stoimost) // 63.07р.
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var stoimost = Number(Number(cena1)+ Number((Number(cena1)*0.1)*5))*Number(dni)+" р.";
```

Как-то так, или изначально цене присвой численное значение типа = 0, и переменной dni присвой численное значение типа = 0.
Или используй JQuery там есть функция parseInt()

Comment: Много лишнего: при умножении обе строки и так будут преобразованы в тип Number. Поэтому ваше выражение можно свести к `(Number(cena1) + cena1*0.1*5)*dni+" р."`. И `parseInt()` никакого отношения ни к данной ситуации, ни тем более к jQuery не имеет.

Answer (score 0):

Проще сделать в две операции

```
var stoimost = Number(Number(cena1) + Number((Number(cena1)*0.1)*5))*Number(dni);
var stoimost2 = stoimost + " .p"
```